# Continuity of trigonometric function

Tags: calculus

I'm puzzled as to whether the following function is deemed continuous or not:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } x=0\\
2x\sin \frac 1x - \cos \frac1x &\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$$ 
It oscillates a whole lot when x -> 0, and hence would setting y = 0 when x = 0 make it continuous? I also don't see how Squeeze Theorem could be applied over here...

Comment: What are the max and min of $\sin\frac 1x$ and $\cos\frac 1x$? Given those, can you replace your function with two others that squeeze your function?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, MathNoob, though I meant 2x(sin(1/x)) - cos(1/x) but all is well. I don't see how I can squeeze it as assuming I take the lower and upper boundaries of the function, -1 and 1, I would end up having to deal with:

-2x - cos(1/x) <= 2x(sin(1/x)) - cos(1/x) <= 2x - cos(1/x)

Which as x -> 0, cos(1/x) is undefined, no? So is 0 - undefined = 0 or am I doing it in a completely wrong way...?

Comment: If the edit I just did is correct, your function has no limit as $x\to 0$, so the squeeze theorem does not work here. MathNoob thought your function was a bit different.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. That would be my bad for making him think my function was a bit different. So if this function has no limit as x -> 0, then I take it that this function would not be continuous even if f(x) is set to be 0 at x = 0?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The function is discontinuous at $x=0$.

Comment: The $2x\sin(1/x)$ part settles down nicely, but the $\cos(1/x)$ part goes nuts.

Comment: @LeviMedia I guess you are probably dealing with the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } x=0\\
x^2 \sin\frac1x &\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$$  You are checking if it is $C^1$ at zero, aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: A function is continious at a point $c$ if $\lim_{x\to c}=f(c)$. Because the function is otherwise well defined and has no other discontinious points, all you need to prove is that the limit is in fact 0 at 0. Try using the squeeze theorem for finding the limit.